# Silverlight 4 NavigationService page not found

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0

I'm checking if a certain users has the rights to visit a page. When they are not allowed to be there I redirect them.

However, The page exsists but the redirecting part doesn't want to work. It keeps giving me a

```
Page not found: "/AccessDenied"
```

error.

Here is what I got as code.

```
 if ((currentUser.UserType.ManageUsers))
                {
                    if (NavigationService != null)
                        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AccessDenied", UriKind.Relative));
                }
                else
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ((UsersViewModel)DataContext).LoadAll());
                    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "~/AccessDenied" (assuming the page is in the same project)

Comment: It is in the same project. Same error. I am calling that redirect in the OnNavigatedTo function btw